# Interrogating the results of a Markov-chain simulation - Help and feedback highly appreciated

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, simulation, python

I have built a Markov chain which simulates the daily routine of German residents (activity patterns). Each simulation day is divided into 144-time steps and the person can carry out one of fourteen activities. Those are:
 Away - work (1)
 Away - leisure (2)
 Away - shopping (3)
 Sleeping (4)
 Cooking (5)
 Using dishwasher (6)
 Doing laundry (7)
 Vacuuming (8)
 Watching TV (9)
 Using PC (10)
 Personal hygiene (11)
 Ironing (12)
 Listening to music (13)
 Other (14)

In my analysis, I want to link some of these activities to appliances in order to generate electricity load profiles for households.

I calculated the transition probabilities for the Markov chain from a data set containing a total of 226 diaries of persons who documented their activities in a 10-minute interval. The data set can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/tyjvh810eg5brkr/data?dl=0

I have now simulated 4000 days with the Markov chain and now I want to validate the results by comparing them with the original data set.

For this purpose, I analyse the results for the activities individually by calculating the expected value as well as the 95% confidence interval for each time step. Then I check if the mean value for the activity from the original dataset is within this interval. Moreover, I calculate the number of all points that do not lie within the upper or lower threshold of the confidence interval. See the picture below for the results for a simulation for 4000 days. Please note that the y-axis has different values for each activity since they do not all equally appear in the original data set (sleeping is more likely to happen over the day than, for instance, ironing).

[Results for a 4000 days simulation. Grey area is the 95% confidence interval while the blue line is the mean value for each time step calculated from the original data set.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6f5Y.png)

The deviations, however, vary greatly for each simulation. I, therefore, performed the same simulation 4 times and could observe deviations ranging from 1% to more than 10%. The following table shows the results of my simulations.

[Results for the four simulations. each simulation has been done for 4000 days.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1F5IC.png)

Now I wonder, if these results are realistic and if such extreme deviations are possible at all at stochastic simulations or if my Markov chain probably has some mistakes in the code.

I could explain the differences by the fact that the original data set is too small to estimate the probabilities for the Markov chain correctly. However, activities such as "Sleeping" often occur in the original data set, but these values also vary greatly in the results.

I highly appreciate any feedback or help that you can provide.

Thanks,
Felix

Edit: This is the formula that I used to calculate the transition probabilities in Python:

```
# import necessary libraries

# First, create a 143xarray for transition probability matrix since the first state of the activity pattern will be determined by the starting probability which will be calculated later.

data= data(Dataframe vom dataset see link above)

# in case activity is not observed in time step t, return 0 instead divide by 0

def a1(x, y):
    try:
        return x / y
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0

#create matrix for transition probabilities
matrix = np.empty(shape=(143, 14, 14))

#iterate through each time step and calculate probabilities for each activity (from state j to state m)

#save matrix as 3D-array
h=data
for i in range(0, 143):
    for j in range(1, 15):
        for m in range(1, 15):
            a = a1(len(h[(h.iloc[:, i] == j) & (h.iloc[:, i + 1] == m)]), len(h[h.iloc[:, i] == j]))
            matrix[i, j - 1, m - 1] = a
np.save(einp_wi_week, matrix)

# now calculate starting probabilities for time step 0 (initial start activity)

matrix_original_probability_starting_state= np.empty(shape=(14, 1))
for i in range(0, 1):
    for j in range(1, 15):
        a = a1(len(h[(h.iloc[:, i] == j)]), len(h.iloc[:, i]))
        matrix_original_probability_starting_state[j - 1, i] = a
np.save(einp_wi_week_start, matrix_original_probability_starting_state)


# import transition probabilities for markov-chain (I have several worksheets to keep track of my approach and to document the results)


# MARKOV-CHAINS TO GENERATE ACTIVITY PATTERNS


# for every time step, the markov-chain can be either in one of these states / activities
states = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14"]

# Possible sequences of state changes (since transferring from state 1 to state 11, for instance has the same code as transferring from 11 to 1, all state transfers for 1 to a number higher than 9 is adjusted in the transfer code)
transitionName = [["11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "0110", "0111", "0112", "0113", "0114"], ["21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "210", "211", "212", "213", "214"], ["31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "310", "311", "312", "313", "314"], ["41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", "410", "411", "412", "413", "414"], ["51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "510", "511", "512", "513", "514"], ["61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69", "610", "611", "612", "613", "614"], ["71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "710", "711", "712", "713", "714"], ["81", "82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "810", "811", "812", "813", "814"], ["91", "92", "93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "910", "911", "912", "913", "914"], ["101", "102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "1010", "1011", "1012", "1013", "1014"], ["111", "112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", "119", "1110", "1111", "1112", "1113", "1114"], ["121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", "128", "129", "1210", "1211", "1212", "1213", "1214"], ["131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", "137", "138", "139", "1310", "1311", "1312", "1313", "1314"], ["141", "142", "143", "144", "145", "146", "147", "148", "149", "1410", "1411", "1412", "1413", "1414"]]


def activity_forecast(simulation_days):
    # activitypattern is an empty array that stores the sequence of states in the simulation.
    activitypattern = []
    for m in range(0,simulation_days):
        # for each simulation day, the activitypattern for all 144 time steps (10-min resolution) must be generated

        # pro determines the transition probabilities matrix that is used for the simulation day and can be changed with regards to the day simulated (weekday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday). 

        # Need to be changed for the validation in order to validate activity patterns for weekdays, Fridays, Saturdays, and Sundays (see transition probability matrices above and comments later)

        pro = einp_wi_week

        #Determine starting activity. Therefore use vector with starting probabilities for all activites, generated in "Clustern_Ausgangsdaten..."
        activityToday = np.random.choice(states,replace=True,p=einp_wi_week_start[:,0])



        # create array were the sequence of states for simulation day is stored. This array will be appended to the activity pattern array

        activityList = [activityToday]

        #since the first activity state for each simulation day is determined, we have to generate activity states for the 143 following time steps
        for i in range(0,143):
            #create sequence of activities
            if activityToday == "1":
                change = np.random.choice(transitionName[0],replace=True,p=pro[i,0,:])
                if change == "11":
                    activityList.append("1")
                    pass
                elif change == "12":
                    activityToday = "2"
                    activityList.append("2")
                elif change == "13":
                    activityToday = "3"
                    activityList.append("3")
                elif change == "14":
                    activityToday = "4"
                    activityList.append("4")
                elif change == "15":
                    activityToday = "5"
                    activityList.append("5")
                elif change == "16":
                    activityToday = "6"
                    activityList.append("6")
                elif change == "17":
                    activityToday = "7"
                    activityList.append("7")
                elif change == "18":
                    activityToday = "8"
                    activityList.append("8")
                elif change == "19":
                    activityToday = "9"
                    activityList.append("9")
                elif change == "0110":
                    activityToday = "10"
                    activityList.append("10")
                elif change == "0111":
                    activityToday = "11"
                    activityList.append("11")
                elif change == "0112":
                    activityToday = "12"
                    activityList.append("12")
                elif change == "0113":
                    activityToday = "13"
                    activityList.append("13")
                else:
                    activityToday = "14"
                    activityList.append("14")
            elif activityToday == "2":
                change = np.random.choice(transitionName[1],replace=True,p=pro[i,1,:])           
                if change == "22":
                    activityList.append("2")
                    pass
                elif change == "21":
                    activityToday = "1"
                    activityList.append("1")
                elif change == "23":
                    activityToday = "3"
                    activityList.append("3")
                elif change == "24":
                    activityToday = "4"
                    activityList.append("4")
                elif change == "25":
                    activityToday = "5"
                    activityList.append("5")
                elif change == "26":
                    activityToday = "6"
                    activityList.append("6")
                elif change == "27":
                    activityToday = "7"
                    activityList.append("7")
                elif change == "28":
                    activityToday = "8"
                    activityList.append("8")
                elif change == "29":
                    activityToday = "9"
                    activityList.append("9")
                elif change == "210":
                    activityToday = "10"
                    activityList.append("10")
                elif change == "211":
                    activityToday = "11"
                    activityList.append("11")
                elif change == "212":
                    activityToday = "12"
                    activityList.append("12")
                elif change == "213":
                    activityToday = "13"
                    activityList.append("13")
                else:
                    activityToday = "14"
                    activityList.append("14")
            [code is too long - code needs to be written for each activity (1-14)]

        activitypattern.append(activityList)
    # save the files in order to use them later for comparison(and also for documentation since they can change for each simulation)
    df=pd.DataFrame(activitypattern)
    df.to_csv("Activitypatterns_synthetic_one_person_ft_aggregated_week_4000_days_new",index=False)

#call function
activity_forecast(4000)
```

Comment: It would be useful to see the transition probability matrix you used.

Comment: Hi @Ian: I copied my code into my question.

Comment: Hi Ian, did you have time to look at my code that I posted?